# How to count each word in an external webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom, web-applications

This will probably be a simple fix but i can't figure it out. Basically I am opening an external webpage and I want to store each of the words on that webpage (just the words no tags or whatever) into an array so i can output how many times each word occurs on the page.

This is the external page I am using to test:

```
<html>
<body>
<p> Hello world! <br/>
    <a href = ”link.html”> Click <b> here </b> </a>
    <br/> Goodbye world!
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And my output is this:

**Click** : 1 times
**Goodbye world!** : 1 times, 
**Hello world!** : 1 times, 
**here** : 1 times

I am close, I just need "Goodbye world!" and "Hello world!" to split at the space but i can't find a way to do it.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var w;

        function openFile(url) {
            w = window.open();
            w.location = url;
        }

        var mainArray = [];
        var pre;
        function retrieveText() {
            pre = document.getElementById("count");
            getwords(w.document.body);
            count();
        }

        function count() {

            mainArray.sort();

            var current = null;
            var cnt = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < mainArray.length; i++) {
                if (mainArray[i] != current) {
                    if (cnt > 0) {
                        document.write(current + ' : ' + cnt + ' times<br>');
                    }
                    current = mainArray[i];
                    cnt = 1;
                } else {
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
            if (cnt > 0) {
                document.write(current + ' : ' + cnt + ' times');
            }

        }

        function getwords(node) {
            mainArray = w.document.body.innerHTML.replace(/^\s*<[^>]*>\s*|\s*<[^>]*>\s*$|>\s*</g,' ').split(/<[^>]*>/g);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Filename: <input id = "url" name="url" size=15 type="Text"/></p>
<a href="javascript:openFile(document.getElementById('url').value)">
    Open document</a>
</br>
<a href="javascript:retrieveText()">Retrieve text</a><br/>
</br>
<ul id ="arrlist"></ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest not to use regexp to remove tags - potentially it can be difficult to parse any possible HTML. Replace your **getwords()** function with:

```
function getwords(node) {
    mainArray = node.innerText.replace(/\s+/g, ",").split(",");
}
```

In the **mainArray** you can get empty values too, but it's easy to remove them if you need.

I get now:

```
Click : 1 times
Goodbye : 1 times
Hello : 1 times
here : 1 times
world! : 2 times
```

Comment: I just changed the getwords() like you said and now mainArray looks like this for me: ["[object", "HTMLBodyElement]"]

Comment: I tried a little modified example, because my Chrome doesn't allow reading local files. For your situation try this only one line for a function: **mainArray = node.innerText.replace(/\s+/g, ",").split(",");**

Comment: that worked! thank you my friend :) could you edit the answer you posted so i can mark it as solved?